# Oracle SQL filter rows after pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm having an issue while trying to apply a filter to my query after using the pivot command.

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
ovar.object_header_id,
c.name || '[' || oval.sequence || ']' as name,
CASE
  WHEN(oval.value_string IS NOT NULL)
  THEN TO_CHAR(oval.value_string)
  WHEN(cval.value_string IS NOT NULL)
  THEN TO_CHAR(cval.value_string)
  WHEN(oval.value_number IS NOT NULL)
  THEN TO_CHAR(oval.value_number)
  WHEN(cval.value_number IS NOT NULL)
  THEN TO_CHAR(cval.value_number)
  ELSE NULL
END AS value
FROM object_value oval
INNER JOIN object_variant ovar
ON ovar.id = oval.object_variant_id
INNER JOIN characteristic c
ON c.id = oval.characteristic_id
LEFT JOIN characteristic_value cval
ON oval.characteristic_value_id = cval.id
WHERE ovar.object_type_id       = 1374 
)
pivot (
max(VALUE) for (NAME) in ('WTI_AMBIENTE[0]','WTI_TIPO[0]','WTI_UMIDADE[0]','WTI_LINHA_DE_PRODUTO[0]','WTI_ESPACO[0]','WTI_SUBSTRATO[0]','WTI_COR[0]','WTI_ESQUEMA_TINTA[0]','WTI_UMIDADE[1]','WTI_TIPO_AGUA[0]','WTI_VELOCIDADE[0]','WTI_UMIDADE[2]')
);
```

And with it I'm getting a table like this (column names was too big, so changed to numbers)

```
     1       2    3       4       5       6          7        8      9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1003353792  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00001   m10
1003353793  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00001   m11
1003353794  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00001   m1
1003353795  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00002   m14
1003353796  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00002   m15
1003353797  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00001   m12
1003353798  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00002   m13
1003353799  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00002   m18
1003353800  NA  00003   00008   00002   00004   Não Aplica  00001   m19
```

Now I need to filter my new table, let´t say that I want only rows that have "00001" in column 8, but I'm not finding the right code.

I tried this at the end, but without success (compiler said that "VALUE" is not valid)

```
WHERE (NAME, VALUE) IN (
 ('WTI_UMIDADE' , '00006')
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Was there a name `'WTI_UMIDADE'` in the `NAME` column? It is **not included** in the `IN` list of `PIVOT`, so whatever values corresponded to this `NAME` are removed completely after `PIVOT`. Or did you mean `'WTI_UMIDADE[0]'`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is after the Pivot your columns have new name

So you should use

```
WHERE [WTI_UMIDADE] = '00006'
```

Comment: Actually there is no concept of "your columns" and there are no columns that have been given new names. Rather, PIVOT removes some of the old columns, and instead creates new **columns**. (There is no column that had an old name and now has a new one.) And, instead of checking for `NAME = 'WTI_UMIDADE' and VALUE=<whatever>`, now the value to check is in a **new** *column*, labeled `"WTI_UMIDADE[0]"`. (By the way, the newly created columns should be given standard names, that don't require double-quotes... that's a side issue.)

Comment: @mathguy First you are correct, looks like is a language difference issue there, I thought obvious, but I also was referring to the new columns there, Second the column name is confusing, OP use three different ones, I choose the one on the compassion, but looks like the new columns is named `WTI_UMIDADE[0]`

Comment: Thanks Juan and Mathguy, I joined your both answers, using in pivot the "WTI_UMIDADE[0] as UMIDADE" and    WHERE UMIDADE = '00006'

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
select * from ( **yourSql** ) where "'dynamicFieldName'" in ('a', 's', 'd')
```